# Matrix multiplication on dataframe in R?

Tags: r

Is there an established/best practice way to matrix multiply a data.frame, as opposed to an object of strictly `matrix` class? That is, is there an alternative to or variation of `%*%` that happily accepts data.frames?

The sole purpose is to save the clutter of the extraneous code used to convert the data.frame to a matrix before providing it to `%*%`.

E.g. this

```
as.matrix(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(5,6,7))) %*% c(2,2)
```

could simplify to

```
data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(5,6,7)) %*% c(2,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sweep` to multiply the values in dataframe with vector and then use `rowSums`.

```
rowSums(sweep(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(5,6,7)), 2, c(2, 2), `*`))
#[1] 12 16 20
```

---

Another method is to transpose the dataframe and multiply and then take `colSums` however, transposing converts dataframe to matrix.

```
colSums(t(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(5,6,7))) * c(2, 2))
```

Comment: The implicit conversion from df to matrix isn't a problem, it's just the code itself that I will try to reduce. These methods are great to know but are still about as wordy as the original method. Do you know if there's any direct replacement for `%*%` that accepts a `data.frame` (I guess we could define one, but I wonder if something has already been established)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware of a function which directly works on dataframes (like matrix). Perhaps, it is better to define your own function.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiply `data.frame`s like so

```
library(mmr)

x <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(5,6,7))
y <- c(2,2)


mm(x, y)
#   V1
# 1 12
# 2 16
# 3 20

x %mm% y
#   V1
# 1 12
# 2 16
# 3 20
```